# Validate multiple emails with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two functions:

```
validateEmail: function(value) {
    var regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
return (regex.test(value)) ? true : false;
}

validateEmails: function(string) {

    var self = shareEmail;
    var result = string.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);

        for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
            if(!self.validateEmail(result[i])) {
                return false;
            } else {               
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I test the email like this `if(!self.validateEmails(multipleEmails)) {` i get true or false based only on the first email in the string, but I want to test for any email in the string.

Thank you!

Comment: What contains multipleEmails ?

Comment: `^` and `$` in the regex makes it match the whole string. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html to learn more about regular expressions

Comment: @Bartimeus It's the value of a text input... basically a string with email(s) separated by a comma or semicolon.

Comment: @Znarkus I am separating each email with split function and test for each one.

Comment: @FlorescuAdrian Oh now I understand. The answers below should solve your problem

Comment: Do you want `true` if all emails are OK or if any one email is OK?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is your if/else block; You are returning under both conditions. Which means that it leaves the function after evaluating only one element.

I've modified validateEmails to demonstrate what you probably want to do:

```
validateEmail: function(value) {
    var regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return (regex.test(value)) ? true : false;
}

validateEmails: function(string) {
    var self = shareEmail;
    var result = string.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);

    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
        if(!self.validateEmail(result[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: How is it possible I didn't see it... x)

Comment: @Gustonez Solved my problem because it's exiting the function when the if statement reaches a invalid email. This is what I was looking for, but I love your solution to because it's showing the wrong email(s) also!

Comment: when I am writing the regex string it is giving error in this portion "@([\w-]+\.)" that invalid expression term '['

Comment: Hi @Lucas Green, can you update your answer in fiddle, it was very useful for others

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```
validateEmails: function(string) {

    var self = shareEmail;
    var result = string.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);
    var errors = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
        if(!self.validateEmail(result[i])) {
            errors[i] = result[i] + ' is not valid.';
        }
     }
     if (errors.length > 0) {
        alert(errors.join('\n'));
        return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

in case you use jquery-validate the validation method would look like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("separated_emails", function(value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    var mails = value.split(/,|;/);
    for(var i = 0; i < mails.length; i++) {
        // taken from the jquery validation internals
        if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(mails[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}, "Please specify a email address or a comma separated list of addresses");
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, although I used different RegEx expression to have an improved invalid email coverage: ```/^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/```

Comment: @mik-t, can you paste your answer in the fiddle, it will help for others

Comment: @whoami that should probably be addressed to **staabm**, I've simply used the solution above, albeit with different RegEx expression

Comment: The one I used originally is the one recommended by the W3C

Answer (score 1):

I find the most maintainable way is to use a variable to store the return output.

```
validateEmail: function(value) {
    var regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
return (regex.test(value)) ? true : false;
}

validateEmails: function(string) {

var self = shareEmail;
var result = string.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);
var allOk = true;


    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
        if(!self.validateEmail(result[i])) {
            allOk = false;
        } 
    }

return allOk;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below is perfect to validate multiple email addresses separated with comma or semicolon using JQuery:

```
   var emailReg = new RegExp(/^([A-Z0-9.%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,6})*([,;][\s]*([A-Z0-9.%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,6}))*$/i);
      var emailText = $('#email').val();
      if (!emailReg.test(emailText)) {
          alert('Wrong Email Address\Addresses format! Please reEnter correct format');
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer does not respond to the OP’s specific problem.