# jQuery: Validate Multiple Emails

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

So I found these two functions:

```
validateEmail: function(value) {
    var regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return (regex.test(value)) ? true : false;
}

validateEmails: function(string) {
    var self = shareEmail;
    var result = string.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);

    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
        if(!self.validateEmail(result[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

from this question: 
[Validate multiple emails with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105513/validate-multiple-emails-with-javascript)

Can anyone tell me what does the variable "**shareEmail**" mean ? It is not defined and I don't understand what it means, what is it's purpose?

Comment: You would have to ask the original questioner, that variable was already undefined in his code.

Comment: Probably just a reference the the "validate" object so it can call the function `validateEmail`.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging.  Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the code you didn't show looks like this:

```
showEmail = {

    validateEmail: function(value) {
        var regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        return (regex.test(value)) ? true : false;
    },

    validateEmails: function(string) {
        var self = shareEmail;
        var result = string.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);

        for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
            if(!self.validateEmail(result[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

};
```

In which case `shareEmail`'s value is self-evident.